# Data Modeling, Primary Keys, TOAD?

Tags: data

Is there software i can use to create a data model of sharePoint lists and libraries like there is TOAD for SQL databses

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the database model for SharePoint dont have foreign keys, so using ER tools like TOAD Data Modeller and Rational Rose to the database and generate charts is not very useful since you dont get the relations.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few 3rd-party commercial 'design' tools but most are specific to the design task - for e.g., Metadata (MetaVis Architect), BCS (Lightning Tools' BCS Metaman) and several others. You may want to review the various tools in the catalog at the [SharePoint Reviews](http://www.sharepointreviews.com/product-directory.html) site.

In addition to [SharePoint Designer 2010](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82905/A-Visual-Guide-in-designing-Sharepoint-2010), the upcoming [Visual Studio 2012 has some new designer features for SharePoint development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee290856%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [LINQ to SharePoint DSL Extension for Visual Studio 2010](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/linq2spdsl). It allows to design a site graphically, then it generate assets.

I never used it in a real project, evaluate it before choose.